# Getting buttons to stretch full screen with Tailwind

Tags: html, layout, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get buttons to stretch across the screen with tailwind, but either they align left and don't stretch out (most cases), or - as in the current state of the code, they seem to stretch off the right hand side of the screen!

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but can't see what it is. My header and footer stretch appropriately, and originally I just duplicated them, but as `button`s, not `div`s.

Code (stretching off screen version) currently looks like this:

```
<body>
...
<div class="">
    <div class="block">
        <ul class="">
            <li><button class="w-full bg-orange-200 hover:bg-orange-400 rounded-lg mx-6 my-4">
                    <div class="text-black text-lg content-center">
                        <h2 class="font-bold">Mike's big adventure</h2><br>
                        <div class="text-black text-base">Aargh, zombies!</div>
                        <div class="text-gray-600 text-xs">
                            <div>Created: 2020-03-24T12:57:01.753Z</div>
                            <div>Updated: 2020-03-24T13:00:06.411Z</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </button></li>
            ... more list items
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

(Note, don't think it makes a difference, but the html is actually being generated by an Elm SPA)

How do I need to nest the various `container`, `w-full`, `w-screen`, `button` etc. and what combo do I need to get what I want?

Edit: This snippet isn't the only thing that isn't stretching. For example neither does the page header. The page footer, which is attached to the bottom of the screen, stretches all the way though ...

Header:

```
<div class="container flex-auto w-screen m-2">
   <div class="w-full content-center bg-orange-500 rounded-lg">
      <h1 class="font-bold text-5xl text-center">Header</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Footer:

```
<div class="container flex-auto w-screen mx-2">
   <div class="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 bg-orange-500 rounded-lg m-2">
      <div class="m-4">Footer</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the w-screen class inside of the button?

Comment: TBH, not sure what combos I've tried -seems like everything. But I just tried that and it didn't help - it still stretches off the screen to the right.

Answer (score 9):

You should make the `<li>` full width since the button is nested in it and take the width of its parent which is the `li`. Add a `w-full` class.

Maybe also try adding a `block` class to the button as well
Add

Comment: Doesn't change I'm afraid. I've added some extra info to the question, since the only thing that stretches the entire width and scales correctly is the footer, which is attached to the bottom of the screen. Everything else is narrower than that for some reason!

Comment: Also, what's the need of giving the footer and header `w-screen`. By default, a div is a block element which takes full width. I don't think that class is necessary. and could possibly be causing issues. If need be, use `w-full` instead.

Comment: It's on GitHub, but not as html. It's generated by Elm, but I copied the html it generates for a minimum reproducible example.  I'll try trimming the outer div classes when I get back to my pc later and see if it helps.

Comment: If I remove the outer div of the header, I end up back with a section that is actually wider than the page area again ... 
`<div class="w-full flex-auto content-center bg-orange-500 rounded-lg m-2"><h1 class="font-bold text-5xl text-center">Header</h1></div>`

Comment: Wait - got it! It seems to be the `w-full` that pushes a div to be wider than the page for some reason!